# Ensure all values in a dataframe column are between two values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this and I want to ensure all values within the column 'T' lie between 129 and 130. i.e. when a value is greater than 130, it should get subtracted until it lies between 129 and 130. Similarly, if the value is less then 129, I want to keep adding 1 til the value lies between 129 and 130.

```
    T
0   129.3
1   129.1
2   128.9
3   128.9
4   128.9
5   129.6
6   129.4
7   129.2
8   130.1
9   129.8
10  129.7
11  130.4
12  130.7
13  127.9
14  130.4
15  130.0
16  129.0
17  128.5
18  128.7
19  129.5
20  129.9
21  130.1
22  129.6
23  129.3
24  128.7
25  128.6
26  128.8
27  129.3
28  129.6
29  129.2
30  129.1
31  129.0
32  128.7
33  128.6
34  128.8
35  129.1
36  129.5
37  130.0
38  129.4
39  129.3
```

For some reason, the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
for i in df['T']: 
    if i<129:
        while i<129:
            i+=1
    if i>130: 
        while i>130:
            i-=1
```

Comment: I think you meant `df['T'][i]`, not just `i`

Comment: Why doesn't `df['col'].clip(129, 130)` work for you?

Comment: I don't want it to be exactly 130 or exactly 129, I want the value to be in between, retaining the initial decimal place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wan't the result the same as when you add or subtract values of 1:

```
import numpy as np
df['T'] = df['T'] % 1 + 129
```

If you just want to bound the values to be between 129 and 130 please use:

```
df['T'] = df['T'].clip(129, 130)
```

Comment: `df['T'] % 1` won't work for values with distance > 1 from either bound.

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering if there is a way around this. Perhaps use a random selection within a preset range instead of 129. However, What if you would want to select the minimum? Say, if the range is 127-133, you would want anything less than 127 to be 127.something and anything more than 133 to be 132.something.

Comment: @coldspeed could you please provide an example of what you mean? `14.5%1+129` will give 129.5, `999.9%1 + 129` will give 129.9. Seems to work at whatever distance.

Comment: @SashaTsukanov I think he meant to say if you increased the range of the bounds. Right now, the bound is apart by 1. `for i in df[df['T']<lower bound]:df['T'] = df['T'] % 1 + lower bound` will always work.